# iOS app for marking businesses on a personalized map

Tags: iphone, ios, software-recommendation, maps

I need an app for iPhone (iOS 8) that would:

- allow me to save places on a map and group them by categories (e.g. restaurants, bars, clubs, ...)
- be more useful if I could change the name of the locations and add some comments to remember details of the place
- filter by categories and geolocation (e.g. to see only restaurants or only bars that are close to me)

Comment: You mean sth like Foursquare? https://itunes.apple.com/de/app/foursquare/id306934924?mt=8

Answer (score 3):

Sounds like an opportunity to create an app!

Google Maps allows you to save your own maps (My Maps) where you can add locations and place short notes about them. You can not categorize or sort.

With Yelp, you can save locations and make notes, but its limited beyond those features.

The closest I have seen to what you are seeking is an app and website called [Findery](https://findery.com/). It is a mapping app that allows you to save and create notes on specific locations. you can include links, videos etc if you like. While these notes are meant to be 'found' by others, you can make them private. In addition, it has a feature called 'Notemaps' that allows you to categorize your notes in separate maps, like 'Been here', or 'favorites' etc.

I am not affiliated with any of these, just a user.

Answer (score 1):

Search for mapstr app on apple store.. It helps you to “never forget places” .. This iPhone app lets you pin places you’ve loved in the past or want to try out in the future, and there are both map and list views to help you keep track of your venues.

Answer (score 1):

I'm the founder of [Mapstr](http://mapstr.com)... And I don't know how to describe it better than you did with your requirements.

It's just the exact same app you describe:

- It allows you to save places on a map and group them by categories (e.g. restaurants, bars, clubs, ...).
- You can change the name of the location and add some comments to remember what the place was.
- You are able to filter by categories, e.g. to see only restaurants or only bars that are close to you.

Comment: Thanks for self disclosing your authorship. Being modest and honest and helpful is a great way to promote your work and not run afoul of community efforts to keep spam in check.